# WebView text is blurry, then flashes, then clear

Tags: c#, webview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a `WebView` in a Window 8.1 app that I'm putting some HTML in using `NavigateToString`. The `WebView` loads the html and the text is blurry. The `WebView` then flashes and all the text gets really small, then it goes back to the size it should be again. The text is now really crisp and clear. It's like the styling completely goes away and it's all rendered again.

What is going on here? Is there a way of preventing this?

If I set a breakpoint on `WebView.Navigate`, this doesn't happen.